# How to define a type with sequence numbers in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to define a type with 1-31, such as :

```
type DAYS = 1 | 2 | .... | 31;
```

So, has some methods like this ?

```
type DAYS = 1..31;
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [other, correct, answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70459690/2887218), there is no such feature provided by the language, and [microsoft/TypeScript#15480](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480) is the relevant open feature request.

If you are using TypeScript 4.5+, and your ranges are non-negative whole numbers less than 1000 and you don't mind making the compiler go through a lot of effort to calculate small numbers, you can use a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) that use [variadic tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to build up arrays of arrays of varying lengths, and then get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of those lengths:

```
type LessThan<N extends number, A extends any[] = []> =
  N extends A['length'] ? A[number] : LessThan<N, [...A, A['length']]>

type NumericRange<F extends number, T extends number> = 
  Exclude<T | LessThan<T>, LessThan<F>>
```

You can try it on your `Days` type, and it works:

```
type Days = NumericRange<1, 31>
/* type Days = 1 | 31 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 
   16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 */
```

Note that union ordering is an implementation detail, and the compiler tends to put types it's already seen before earlier in the union, so this is correct (every number from `1` to `31` is present) but weird (since the `31` shows up after the `1` and before the `2`).

Of course if you're only using it once, to create `Days` then it's *definitely* not worth it, since there are more characters in the implementation of `NumericRange` than there are in writing out the `Days` type manually.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhDO8AqALAhgOwDwDkoQA9gIMATeKDAVwFsAjCAJwBooBBfIk8qTEAbQC6UALxQhAPlEAoKFDyFiZCm34ByADYkA5sBRrhAfnb9q9JsIBcsBMnTYcrfgDpXbVqs069BwROnSoJDytEwAlgDGAEqY2hBYAGKcSjxmDCxQSMncFGlMUmIAogQRGlSk8VkAPjaIqJhYSBKscHX2iRL+geDQACJoIBRiOKGMkTEYcVgAjKwAzNP+APQAVFBBfQNDUNNQNQt7UABMh3OHACyHAKyHAGyHAOyHAByHAJyH0wAMn7s10yd-md-pd-jcarI5NN7v8nv9Xv8PjUjj9kX9joDjsDjqDjuDjjDjnDjgjjkioHMfislgEgA)

Comment: It's great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll have to write these by hand. See more [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480).

Of course, you could write a code-gen tool if you have *a lot* of these, but it seems like an overkill.