# Is there any way to generate type in typescript for my case?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My expected type:

```js
type AnnuallyRecord = {
  m1: MonthlyRecord,
  m2: MonthlyRecord,
  ...
  m12: MonthlyRecord
}
```

I tried with template literal type and it worked:

```js
type Key = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12
type Month = `m${Key}`

type AnnuallyRecord = {
  [k in Month]: MonthlyRecord;
}
```

But as you can see, I generated the `Key` type myself and I unhappy with it.

So please show me the best way to generate `Month` type if possible.

Comment: Honestly, your definition of `Key` is shorter than anything which would generate the keys automatically.  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdY0Qm), but it's complicated.  Unless you want to generate a range from 1 to 365 or something, I'd say you should just do it the way you're doing it.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I think that’s worth an answer. Your range type may be overkill for 12, but it’s a nice type!

Comment: My "I've done this before" senses were tingling and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70459670/how-to-define-a-type-with-sequence-numbers-in-typescript is essentially the same thing

Comment: @jcalz How magical! It's hard to understand, but I will try to research later. You saved my life.