# TS Union Types from Array always return type string

Tags: typescript, union-types

Based on this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/string-union-to-string-array) I've created some union types from a string[], and it supposes to return a list of valid type values, but instead of that, the type accepts any string value.

```js
const arrayDays = Array.from(Array(32).keys(), (num) =>
  num.toString().padStart(2, '0'),
)
const listDays = [...arrayDays.splice(1)] as const
type Day = (typeof listDays)[number]
```

I've been expecting that type Day will be something like `type Days = '01' | '02' .... | '30' | '31'` but his real type is `string`

[image]

Then if I use the Day type in a variable it will accept any string value.

```js
const day1: Day = '' //not showing it as error
const day2: Dat = 'y' //not showing it as error
```

Comment: Your `arrayDays` is inferred to be `const arrayDays: string[]`, not a specific type of union obtained by "running" your code. (the compiler doesn't even try to "run the code as JS" to figure out the exact content of your array)

Comment: The linked post shows a const assertion on an array _of literals_, where there's type information to preserve. You're applying a const assertion to something that's already just a string array. (Also the way you're handling "00" is baffling.)

Comment: Oh, that's why! So, it needs the exact array of literals with values to do that and not the result of an operation. Thanks, @grsngky

Comment: @jonrshape thanks for your explanation, and for the code review. Now I found another way to exclude the "00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing many people seem to misunderstand is that types only exist at compile time. Which is why in this case `arrayDays` are inferred as `string[]`. There is no way for the compiler to narrow down the type based on a runtime value.

You'll have to preserve that information at compile time to generate a union from your array. Inspired by this beautiful answer from @jcalz (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70468769/12834972) I created a `Day` type that generates a union just like your array that is assigned to `arrayDays` at runtime.

```
type LessThan<
  N extends number,
  A extends any[] = []
> = N extends A["length"]
  ? A[number]
  : LessThan<N, [...A, A["length"]]>;

type Day<
  F extends number = 0,
  T extends number = 31,
  R extends number = Exclude<T | LessThan<T>, LessThan<F>>
> = R extends LessThan<10> ? `0${R}` : `${R}`;

const day1: Day = "-1"; // invalid
const day2: Day = "3"; // invalid
const day3: Day = "03"; // valid
const day4: Day = "32"; // invalid
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhDO8AqALAhgOwDwFgBQUUAclBAB7AQYAm8UGArgLYBGEATgDT6ECCpFKrSiYQAbQC6UALxRJ+AHwziAyjTq8xAIgA2VAObAUWiTygB+KJsasOpglABcsBMnTYinOQDpfvL5q6BkYmEgoA3Pj4oJBQACJoILgOAGKqQnQ2bOzKAAzcDkjp6vTM2coAzACMBYQASsXCWRzKAKJkAMY6DNQQWEUAPi6IqJj9Cl5wI+5YKQoKisoN5GrCU25jVblKlgAGuQAkAN51AL67TlC7x2e7kXj4HQD2GPDAUNSJVc4JIMpaAFoqlpwlAAPRgqAASwwADc0DoodRHi83h9EgAmH6Jf4VEHgyEw+GI5F4Z6vd6fEAVbF-WRaXJ40EQqDEpEoinokAAFlpuIx+JZRIRSKAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @behemoth for the explanation about my mistake, and of course for the solution. It works as expected. The only thing I modified is `F extends number = 1` to avoid including the "00" as a valid day.